# Two partial views in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I am new to MVC3. My task is to render two partial views in one View. A List of data are to be shown in each Partial View, in Telerik Grid. And I wanted to show both Partial Views in one level ie in one Row. I have tried to use PanelBar(), but the Partial Views are shown in line by line mode. I want the result shown as below :

[image]

```
@using EY.Benchmarking.Entities.Administration;
@model IEnumerable<Measure>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Roles";
int PageSize = 10; // This needs to be fetched from a global variable   
}
@(
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("RoleList")
    .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(o => o.MeasureID))
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
            .Ajax()
            .OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Client) // <-- set the operation mode
            .Select("RoleList", "RoleMapping")
            )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.MeasureID).Visible(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.MeasureName);
    })
    .Pageable(paging => // Set the pagingation and associated propeties
        {
            paging.PageSize(PageSize).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndInput).Position(GridPagerPosition.Bottom);
        })
    .Sortable()
    .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
    .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;" })
)
```

Comment: Can you just wrap each partial view in a div and place it where you want on the page?

Comment: ok that worked....now is it possible to remove header part from Telerik().Grid ? because in the second partial view shown above, I want the search textbox shown. the code for the partial view is shown above

Comment: I don't think it's possible to remove the header form the grid; it's part of the html that is generated by telerik.  You could try digging into the telerik css files you downloaded if you MUST remove it, but I would not recommend it.  You may be able to hide, or rather cover it, with some .css of your own.

Comment: ok....how about the text box ?

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a one row table in HTML and add both of the partials as cells.
     
    
    first partial here second partial here

or you can use a telerik splitter.

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Splitter()
        .Name("LayoutSplitter")
        .Panes(panes =>
        {
            panes.Add()
            .Content("Left pane");

        panes.Add()
            .Content("Right pane");
    })
%>
```

source: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-splitter-introduction.html